# Swift BLE "didDiscoverServices" not executing. Am I missing something?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been reading the tutorial to use the nRF8001 from Adafruit and connecting it to an iOS device via Arduino. So far I've set up everything correctly and it works fine in their app.
I'm trying to write my own app that (for now) does the exact same thing, I read their tutorial and from what I understand I copied the code as close as I could, so far I can get the connection and most things seem to be working (UI-wise), however I can't seem to do anything past connecting to the device:
Here's my code for AFTER connecting:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        //What to do when it discovers a peripheral, add it to the array list
        print("Peripheral found: " + (peripheral.name ?? "Unknown Name"))
        peripheralsFoundNames.append((peripheral.name ?? "Unknown Name"))
        peripheralsFoundData.append((advertisementData.description ))
        peripheralsFoundCB.append(peripheral)
        peripheralsFoundRSSIs.append(RSSI)
    }

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected to device!")
        displayStatusAlert(localmsg: "Connection Succesful!")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: DEVICE_READY_KEY), object: self)
        data?.length = 0 //clear any data that might be stored
        peripheral.discoverServices([BLETemperatureService])
        print("Here at didConnect, connected to:" + peripheral.name!)
        // Here needs to add code to check if it's a single or multi-channel device via the advertisement data or some other constant, maybe the name?
    }
```

As you can see, I am calling explicitly peripheral.discoverServices, and then i have a print statement that executes. Then I have the following (NOTE NONE OF THE BELOW LINES SEEM TO EXECUTE AT ANY TIME (AT LEAST NOT THE PRINT STATEMENTS):

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    print("here at diddisoverservices")
        if ((error) != nil){
            displayStatusAlert(localmsg: "Error: \n" + (error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error Unknown" ))
        }

        guard let services = peripheral.services
            else{
                return
        }

        for service in services {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)

        }
        print ("Discovered!")
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if ((error) != nil){
            displayStatusAlert(localmsg: "Error: \n" + (error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error Unknown" ))
        }

        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics
            else{
                return
        }
        for characteristic in characteristics {
            //looks for the right characteristic
            print("looking for characteristic")


            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(BLERXCharacteristic)  {
                deviceConnectedRXChar = characteristic

                //Once found, subscribe to the this particular characteristic
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: deviceConnectedRXChar!)

                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Rx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(BLETXCharacteristic){
                deviceConnectedTXChar = characteristic
                print("Tx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            peripheral.discoverDescriptors(for: characteristic)
        }

        print ("Characteristic discovered")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        if characteristic == deviceConnectedRXChar {
            if let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                receivedDataString = ASCIIstring
                print("Value Recieved: \((receivedDataString as String))")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: DEVICE_SENT_DATA), object: nil)

            }
        }
```

Comment: First: Could you show the `didDiscoverPeripheral` and that you have a strong reference on peripheral? Second: If you do `peripheral.discoverServices(nil)`, does it work?

Comment: Added didDiscoverPeripheral code, additionally, tried with (nil) and still get the same results (the print "here at diddiscoverservices" doesn't run)

Comment: After `peripheralsFoundCB.append(peripheral)`, you never called `central.connect(peripheral, options:[])` It discovered it, but it didn't start a connection. A device is limited of simultaneous connection, and if you are in environment with hundreds of device, hopefully it's like that.

Comment: I do connect, the thing is that it's not there in that code. You asked for "didConnect" and that runs AFTER connection, the fact that that piece of code does run (print peripheral found:) means that part works. I have another function that connects to the device selected from the list (i populate a list based on the array of devices found). I also get the print statements "connected successfully". And my arduino serial monitor says "Connected"

Comment: Misread, sorry. `peripheral.discoverServices([BLETemperatureService])`, you didn't set before `peripheral.delegate = self`?

Comment: Yes! That seems to be it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)` is a `CBPeripheralDelegate` method.

So what you were missing is setting the `CBPeripheral` object `delegate`.

So just before doing `peripheral.discoverServices([BLETemperatureService])`, you need to do `peripheral.delegate = self`.